# top ten ie7 css bugs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

What css properties you avoid building web pages for ie7?
What you usually check first when you see page that does not render well in ie7?

UPD: as a programmer is not a designer usually, i think that it would be useful to collect short list of bugs which generate most share of failures, not going deep into css implementations. Programmer will never know all this staff.

Ie6 is leaving, Ie7 therefore is a most source of failures.

Comment: I sense a similar thread for IE6 coming.

Comment: for IE6, it would be more like the top 100 IE6 bugs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a great guide on CSS compatibility across browsers [found on **Quirksmode**.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

This compatibility table includes the following browsers:

- Internet Explorer 5.5
- Internet Explorer 6
- **Internet Explorer 7**
- **Internet Explorer as 8 Internet Explorer 7**
- Internet Explorer 8 as Internet Explorer 8
- FireFox 2
- FireFox 3.0
- FireFox 3.1b
- Safari 3.0 Win
- Safari 3.1 Win
- Safari 4.0b Win
- Chrome 1
- Chrome 2
- Opera 9.62
- Opera 10a
- Konqueror 3.5.7

Studying these tables and more importantly, ***understanding* the browser differences** will probably help you  a lot and is probably worth more than listing a top 10.

**A great book** that explains a lot of in-depth CSS and the reasons why it is rendered differently across browsers is [**CSS Mastery**](http://www.cssmastery.com/). It is my single most favorite CSS book.

Comment: Great list and info, but his question wasn't exactly on cross browser functionality. He specifically asked for IE7.

Comment: I'd say this is the best resource, for anything extra-specific, googling the solution usually works best. Large amounts of CSS blogs to be found covering all the super-weird stuff.

Comment: Like randell commented on the question: "I sense a similiar thread for IE6 coming". I think it's best to focus on *how CSS works* instead of singling out browser bugs for a single browser. The resource above includes pretty much all information needed for Internet Explorer 7 and at the same time, shows the differences between other browsers.

Comment: Well I'm all for answering a question as narrow as possible. We don't know if he is maybe restricted to using IE7 only. In that case he needs to read through a large list of info that you provided instead of getting a narrow answer on his fairly narrow question.

Answer (score 3):

This contains a list of bugs in IE.

Not specific to IE7.

[Explorer Exposed!](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html)

[178 bugs in Internet Explorer  7 for Windows](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/)

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

- http://www.designdetector.com/2006/08/ie7-old-bugs-for-new.php
- http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/ie-bugs.htm

Answer (score 0):

IE7 is already consistent with all common CSS style properties (which I would define as: colors/backgrounds & borders, font styles, and placement (margin, padding, spacing, wrapping)).

Now IE7 doesn't support CSS2 or higher, but I'd say it doesn't even matter because all main CSS rules as stated above are working well.